# Why does len(list) gives type error for a list?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

This is a part of my code :

```
k=int(raw_input(""))

for m in range(k):

q=[]
pseudolis=[]
l=map(int,raw_input("").split())
lenlist=map(int,raw_input("").split())
for i in range(l[1]):
    q.append(int(raw_input("")))
lenlist.sort()
for i in range(len(q)):
    pseudolis=list(lenlist)
    while(len(pseudolis)>0):
        for i in range(pseudolis.__len__()):
            if pseudolis[i]>=q[i]:
                continue
            else:
                flag=0
                break
        else:
            flag=1
        if flag:
            print pseudolis.__len__()
            break
        else:
            pseudolis[1]+=1
            pseudolis=pseudolis[1:].sort()

else:
    print len(pseudolis)
```

Output at some point :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/SNKDWNQL.py", line 66, in <module>
    while(len(pseudolis)>0):
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

I don't get when is the pseudolis getting converted from list type to None type.
I tried using various methods to find len.

Comment: not even sure what the plan is with the map usage.

Comment: @nucleon Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code fails after you're trying to sort your `pseudolis` slice:

```
pseudolis=pseudolis[1:].sort()
```

`list.sort()` doesn't return a list, it returns `None`. Split it as:

```
pseudolis = pseudolis[1:]
pseudolis.sort()
```

Comment: That I'm doing later ; the error is in the while part.

Comment: Sorry, got it.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: That's where your `pseudolis` turns to `None` and then fails on the next `while` check.